# Webview JavaFX running with the process

Tags: java, javafx, webview, process

When using webview of javafx, I want it to display a progress bar helps users know it is working,I mean basic programmer so I can refer to the instructions on the Internet and I do the following, but it does not work,please help me

```
        WebEngine webEngine;

        void btnSearch(ActionEvent event) {
                progressBar.indeterminateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            String url = txtURl.getText().trim();
            if (!url.isEmpty()) {
                if (!url.startsWith("http://") || !url.startsWith("https://")) {
                    url = "http://" + url;
                }
                try {
                    webEngine = browser.getEngine();
                    webEngine.load(url);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication12;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;

import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.RUNNING;
import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.SUCCEEDED;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author pc-205
 */
public class JavaFXApplication12 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final WebView webview = new WebView();

        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().setAll(
                createProgressReport(webview.getEngine()),
                webview
        );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        primaryStage.show();

        webview.getEngine().load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * @return a HBox containing a ProgressBar bound to engine load progress and a Label showing load times
     */
    private HBox createProgressReport(WebEngine engine) {
        final LongProperty startTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
        final LongProperty endTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
        final LongProperty elapsedTime = new SimpleLongProperty();

        final ProgressBar loadProgress = new ProgressBar();
        loadProgress.progressProperty().bind(engine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty());

        final Label loadTimeLabel = new Label();
        loadTimeLabel.textProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(
                        elapsedTime.greaterThan(0))
                .then(
                        Bindings.concat("Loaded page in ", elapsedTime.divide(1_000_000), "ms")
                )
                .otherwise(
                        "Loading..."
                )
        );

        elapsedTime.bind(Bindings.subtract(endTime, startTime));
        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case RUNNING:
                        startTime.set(System.nanoTime());
                        break;

                    case SUCCEEDED:
                        endTime.set(System.nanoTime());
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        HBox progressReport = new HBox(10);
        progressReport.getChildren().setAll(
                loadProgress,
                loadTimeLabel
        );
        progressReport.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        progressReport.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

        return progressReport;
    }

}
```

This program will help in tracking the progress and time taken to load the webpage. **createProgressReport** returns the HBox which contains a progressbar and a label. progressbar shows how much page is loaded . while the page is being loaded the label will show "loading..." and upon completion it will show total **ms** took to load the page

Comment: Thanks for your great help.Your statement with some sites, it will be able to run two case RUNNING. Ex http://www.dantri.com => so I think that should be used loadURL in the createProgressReport :D